# How can I do a bulk caller ID lookup (reverse phone lookup) on a list of phone numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, bulk, caller-id

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I need to do to bulk look-up of many phone numbers?](https://superuser.com/questions/410627/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-bulk-look-up-of-many-phone-numbers)

I have a tab-delimited text file with all of the phone numbers I've called or received calls from in the past year. The phone numbers are all based in the US, so the format is ###-###-####. For tax purposes, I need to know which calls were personal and which ones were business-related. I could enter them all one-by-one into Google, but that will take forever because there are hundreds of numbers to check.

Is there a program, MS Office plugin, or website that I can use to look up all of the numbers at once? If not, is there some way to create an Excel macro to do the lookups for me?

Comment: Thanks. I've never had any luck in the past getting a question reopened after it was closed, but I guess I'll try that again next time.

Comment: Sure. please `delete` this instance of the question though – so we don't have the duplicates lying around! Cheers!

Comment: Oops, now it says I have to wait 2 days to delete it, to allow for reopening. I guess I'll try to remember to delete it later.